# How to copy n files together to a new file of which names are passed as parameters to a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I try to copy *n* files together to a new file of which file names are passed as parameters to a `.bat` file. But the batch file overwrites the results file instead of concatenating the file contents on each iteration of the **GOTO** loop.

The batch file is:

```
:repeat
shift
If "%1" =="" goto :end
copy /y %0+%1 fisx.txt
goto :repeat
:end
```

For example:
If `file1.txt` has the content `abc`, `file2.txt` has the content `def` and `file3.txt` has the content `ijl`, the output is `defijl` instead of wanted `adcdefijl` on calling the batch file with `file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt`.

Are there any parameters that I need to add to not overwrite or how should I solve this?

Comment: Although I said it previously, and someone decided it was not worth saying and deleted it for me, I'm going to say it again nonetheless. Please clarify the intent, currently the only way that the resulting file can contain a single line `abcdefijl` given three lines containing `abc`, `def`, and `ijl` respectively, is if none of those contain line terminators. That would be rare, (very unusual), which is why you should clarify it. Without doing so, I'm not sure how either of the two current answers can achieve your goal, because their line terminators would output results to three line files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The copying loop cannot work by design as expected by you. Let´s say the batch file is called with the arguments `file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt`. What does happen now?

The string used to call the batch file (argument 0) is replaced by `file1.txt` (argument 1) and the other two arguments are also shifted left in the arguments list. Therefore `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` are copied together to file `fisx.txt`.

On next loop iteration `file1.txt` (argument 0) is replaced by `file2.txt` and `file3.txt` becomes argument 1. Then are copied together `file2.txt` and `file3.txt` to file `fisx.txt`. So the content of `file1.txt` is ignored completely on this second copying operation as neither existing `fisx.txt` nor `file1.txt` is used on second copying operation replacing existing file `fisx.txt` from the first copying operation.

The working code is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if "%~1" == "" exit /B
copy /B /Y %1 "fisx.txt" >nul
:Repeat
shift
if "%~1" == "" exit /B
copy /B /Y "fisx.txt"+%1 "fisx.txt" >nul
goto Repeat
```

The more enhanced version below supports also empty argument strings and a not correct quoted last argument string.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
:FindFirst
set "NextFile=%~1"
if defined NextFile goto CopyFirst
set "NextFile=%1"
if not defined NextFile exit /B
shift
goto FindFirst
:CopyFirst
copy /B /Y "%NextFile:"=%" "fisx.txt" >nul
:Repeat
shift
set "NextFile=%~1"
if defined NextFile copy /B /Y "fisx.txt"+"%NextFile:"=%" "fisx.txt" >nul & goto Repeat
set "NextFile=%1"
if defined NextFile goto Repeat
```

This version of the code supports also an argument list like:

```
"" "" file1.txt "" "file2.txt" file3.txt"
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains referencing batch file arguments.
- `copy /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?` ... called implicitly by `cmd.exe` before exiting processing of the batch file.
- `exit /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `shift /?`

See also:

- Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `>nul`.
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of operator `&`.
- [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)

Answer (score 1):

Your code simply overwrites the contents of file `fisx.txt` with the concatenation of the last two files in the arguments list.

Rather than copy, simply append.

Overwrite `fisx.txt` with the first file in the arguments list and append every subsequent file (in the arguments list) to file `fisx.txt`

```
type %1 >fisx.txt
:repeat
shift
If "%1" == "" goto :end
type %1 >>fisx.txt
goto :repeat
:end
```

Comment: This code works for text files as asked for in the question, but does not work for binary files. But more problematic is `If "%1" == "" goto :end` which results in the error message `& was unexpected at this time.` and an exit of batch file processing by `cmd.exe` running the batch file with `file1.txt "Development & Test!.txt" file3.txt` as arguments list.

Comment: Output redirection is most natural command line way to do that. I agree.